# SideMenu. Как сделать подпункты

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Привет всем. Ребят, не могу понять, как вообще можно сделать кастомное меню? Вот к примеру у меня есть UserControl:

```
<!-- Menu Items -->
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=MenuItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:SideMenuItem Style="{Binding ItemContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

имеющий в codebehind два свойства зависимости MenuItems( родительская коллекция списка меню ) и ItemContainerStyle( стиль для каждого пункта меню ).
Использую это меню вот так:

```
<local:SideMenu Grid.Column="0" MenuItems="{Binding MenuVM.Categories}">
    <local:SideMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SideMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="NameItem" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Setter Property="Children" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
        </Style>
    </local:SideMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</local:SideMenu>
```

У каждого пункта, представляющим класс SideMenuItem, есть тоже два свойства зависимости - Name( заголовок ) и Children( коллекция дочерних элементов меню ).

Все работает нормально. Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вопрос в том, как сделать подпункты, чтобы они появлялись по нажатию на родительский пункт относительно него с правой стороны. Типа такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вообще это делается? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужно изобретать велосипед, встроенное меню уже есть.

Например, можно сделать так:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrush}">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <!-- вертикальное расположение для меню верхнего уровня -->
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- центрирование элементов -->
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <MenuItem Header="Шкатулки"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Иконы"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Панно">
        <MenuItem Header="Fürstenzug"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Полтавская баталия"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Распятия"/>
</Menu>
```

Единственное, что тут работает не так — подменю открывается вниз, а не вправо.

К сожалению, прямого управления расположением подменю нету. Но это не большая проблема.

Подменю открывается в отдельном [`Popup`'е](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup?view=netframework-4.7.1). Заглядывая в [определение класса `MenuItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem?view=netframework-4.7.1), мы видим

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Popup", Type = typeof(Popup))]
```

что означает, что доступ к этому внутреннему элементу можно получить по имени `"PART_Popup"`.

Для этого проще всего навесить attached property. Идею и реализацию я стащил из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011313/276994).

Кладём attached property:

```
static class MenuExtensions
{
    // стандартное attached property
    public static PlacementMode GetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu) =>
        (PlacementMode)menu.GetValue(MenuPlacementProperty);

    public static void SetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu, PlacementMode value) =>
        menu.SetValue(MenuPlacementProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuPlacementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MenuPlacement",
            typeof(PlacementMode),
            typeof(MenuExtensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PlacementMode.Bottom, OnMenuPlacementChanged));

    // вызывается при изменении значения
    static void OnMenuPlacementChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = o as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem == null)
            return;
        if (menuItem.IsLoaded) // загружен => шаблон уже применён
        {
            UpdatePopupPlacement(menuItem);
        }
        else                   // иначе дожидаемся конца загрузки
        {
            RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
            handler = (oo, ee) =>
                {
                    UpdatePopupPlacement(menuItem);
                    menuItem.Loaded -= handler;
                };
            menuItem.Loaded += handler;
        }
    }

    static void UpdatePopupPlacement(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", menuItem) is Popup popup)
            popup.Placement = GetMenuPlacement(menuItem);
    }
}
```

Имея это в своём распоряжении, можно навесить его на `MenuItem`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Панно" local:MenuExtensions.MenuPlacement="Right">
```

(Ну и чтобы не повторять код, можно поместить это в стиль.)

Результат:

[image: а что у нас в меню?]

---

Если нам нужно ещё, к примеру, сдвинуть `Popup`, нужно немного дополнить код. Я прорефакторил `MenuExtensions`, получилось вот что:

```
static class MenuExtensions
{
    #region attached property PlacementMode MenuPlacement
    public static PlacementMode GetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu) =>
        (PlacementMode)menu.GetValue(MenuPlacementProperty);

    public static void SetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu, PlacementMode value) =>
        menu.SetValue(MenuPlacementProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuPlacementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MenuPlacement",
            typeof(PlacementMode),
            typeof(MenuExtensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                PlacementMode.Bottom,
                (o, args) => NowOrOnLoaded(o, UpdatePopupPlacement)));
    #endregion

    #region attached property Point MenuOffset
    public static Point GetMenuOffset(MenuItem menu) =>
        (Point)menu.GetValue(MenuOffsetProperty);

    public static void SetMenuOffset(MenuItem menu, Point value) =>
        menu.SetValue(MenuOffsetProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuOffsetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MenuOffset",
            typeof(Point),
            typeof(MenuExtensions),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                default(Point),
                (o, args) => NowOrOnLoaded(o, UpdatePopupOffset)));
    #endregion

    static void NowOrOnLoaded(DependencyObject o, Action<MenuItem> a)
    {
        var menuItem = o as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem == null)
            return;
        if (menuItem.IsLoaded)
        {
            a(menuItem);
        }
        else
        {
            RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
            handler = (oo, ee) =>
            {
                a(menuItem);
                menuItem.Loaded -= handler;
            };
            menuItem.Loaded += handler;
        }
    }

    static void UpdatePopupPlacement(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", menuItem) is Popup popup)
            popup.Placement = GetMenuPlacement(menuItem);
    }

    static void UpdatePopupOffset(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", menuItem) is Popup popup)
        {
            var offset = GetMenuOffset(menuItem);
            popup.HorizontalOffset = offset.X;
            popup.VerticalOffset = offset.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Им можно пользоваться так:

```
<MenuItem Header="Панно"
          local:MenuExtensions.MenuPlacement="Right"
          local:MenuExtensions.MenuOffset="15,15"> ...
```

---

Обновление: Я обнаружил баг в `MenuExtensions` (никогда нельзя доверять чужому коду!), и исправил его. Заодно сложный паттерн с подпиской и отпиской заменил на `Task`.

```
static class MenuExtensions
{
    #region attached property PlacementMode MenuPlacement
    public static PlacementMode GetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu) =>
        (PlacementMode)menu.GetValue(MenuPlacementProperty);

    public static void SetMenuPlacement(MenuItem menu, PlacementMode value) =>
        menu.SetValue(MenuPlacementProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuPlacementProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MenuPlacement",
        typeof(PlacementMode),
        typeof(MenuExtensions),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            PlacementMode.Bottom,
            (o, args) => WhenPopupAvailable(o, UpdatePopupPlacement)));
    #endregion

    #region attached property Point MenuOffset
    public static Point GetMenuOffset(MenuItem menu) =>
        (Point)menu.GetValue(MenuOffsetProperty);

    public static void SetMenuOffset(MenuItem menu, Point value) =>
        menu.SetValue(MenuOffsetProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuOffsetProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MenuOffset",
        typeof(Point),
        typeof(MenuExtensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            default(Point),
            (o, args) => WhenPopupAvailable(o, UpdatePopupOffset)));
    #endregion

    static Task TillEvent(
        Action<RoutedEventHandler> subscribe, Action<RoutedEventHandler> unsubscribe)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (o, e) =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            unsubscribe(handler);
        };
        subscribe(handler);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    static async void WhenPopupAvailable(DependencyObject o, Action<Popup, MenuItem> a)
    {
        var menuItem = o as MenuItem;
        if (menuItem == null)
            return;
        if (!menuItem.IsLoaded) // не загружен => дожидаемся
            await TillEvent(h => menuItem.Loaded += h, h => menuItem.Loaded -= h);
        Popup popup = (Popup)menuItem.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", menuItem);
        if (popup == null) // нет ещё попапа?
        {
            var parent = menuItem.Parent as MenuItem;
            if (parent == null) // если нет родителя, тогда непонятна причина, выходим
                return; // для отладки лучше бросить исключение тут
            // если причина в том, что родитель закрыт, подождём пока откроется
            if (!parent.IsSubmenuOpen) 
                await TillEvent(h => parent.SubmenuOpened += h,
                                h => parent.SubmenuOpened -= h);
        }
        popup = (Popup)menuItem.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", menuItem);
        if (popup != null) // если и тут нету, у нас не вышло его достать
            a(popup, menuItem);
    }

    static void UpdatePopupPlacement(Popup popup, MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        popup.Placement = GetMenuPlacement(menuItem);
    }

    static void UpdatePopupOffset(Popup popup, MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        var offset = GetMenuOffset(menuItem);
        popup.HorizontalOffset = offset.X;
        popup.VerticalOffset = offset.Y;
    }
}
```

С этим кодом attached property можно навесить не только на «Панно», но и на «Полтавскую баталию».

---

Чтобы раскрасить фон, нужен такой код:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Blue">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuItemBase">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemBase}"/>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItemBase}">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
```

и дальше как выше.

Comment: Е-мое. Почему так сложно все?:) Неужели сделать свое меню будет намного сложнее, чем Вы описали здесь?:) А можно стиль то у Popup изменить, чтобы было нормальное, красивое меню?

Comment: Блин, был бы у меня в распоряжении C++ и DirectX, я бы это меню за минут 30 накатал...

Comment: @Bretbas: Я своё накатал за две, и ещё за 5 минут нашёл и применил метод перенести Popup вправо. :-P

Comment: @Bretbas: Своё? Попробуйте. Например, вы точно знаете тонкости того, как должен вести себя фокус или Tab? На тяп-ляп я тоже могу, но зачем?

Comment: @Bretbas: И как бы вы организовали на C++ хотя бы возможность стилизации? Если вы сможете написать за день, вы очень крутой программист.

Comment: @Bretbas: Сейчас меню системного вида. Но стиль можно перекрыть, конечно, это ж WPF, тут всё кастомизируется.

Comment: свое, я имел ввиду без расширений таких как стили, шаблоны и тд. Просто чисто меню с callback'ами на каждый пункт.

Comment: @Bretbas: Там на самом деле много тонкостей. Например, посмотрите, как ведёт себя фокус и клавиши в меню (Tab, стрелки вправо/влево, энтер) хотя бы в Visual Studio. И таких тонкостей много, не только с клавиатурой. Всё это придётся писать вручную. Ну или будет не меню, а картинка, которая выглядит как меню, а работает только приблизительно похоже.

Comment: Что-то я не могу понять, а как мне изменить стиль для Popup? При раскрытии? И можно сделать так, чтобы он немного правее был относительно родительского пункта, а то он прям после Header'а идет

Comment: @Bretbas: Дописал по поводу смещения, смотрите.

Comment: @Bretbas: А стиль для Popup'а вам не нужен, меняйте стиль для MenuItem'а.

Comment: Да, и можете объяснить немного про Ваш AttachedProperty. В каком случае будет вызван обработчик `OnMenuPlacementChanged`? Я знаю, что в `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` можно еще передавать callback на `ValueUpdated`. В чем разница между двумя этими callback'ами? Когда нужно использовать один, а когда второй? Еще интересно, что вы делаете конкретно в обработчике `OnMenuPlacementChanged`? Зачем-то проверяете пункт на `IsLoaded`, потом отписываетесь/подписываетесь на событие Loaded. Вообще что это? Как до этого додуматься самому то?

Comment: @Bretbas: Там всё просто, но лучше идёмте в чат по C#, а то эти комментарии прибьют.

Comment: @Bretbas: Исправил баг в MenuExtensions, смотрите.